# How to test unit test a void function in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I'm new to angular and I'm testing my Login component that goes that's something like this.It has a `handleLogin()` function which is void.It redirects to another function as shown below.

[image: loginComponent]

How can I test this function?. It redirects to some other function that also redirects to somewhere else. How to test such a complex function.

Comment: mock it then...:)

Answer (score 3):

```
it('should not be called redirect after login function', () => {
  const loginService = TestBed.inject(LoginService);
  const authService = TestBed.inject(AuthenticationService);
  spyOn(authService, 'isLoggedIn').and.returnValue(false);  // FALSE
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(loginSerive.redirectAfterLogin).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
}

it('should be called redirect after login function', () => {
  const loginService = TestBed.inject(LoginService);
  const authService = TestBed.inject(AuthenticationService);
  spyOn(authService, 'isLoggedIn').and.returnValue(true); 
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(loginSerive.redirectAfterLogin).toHaveBeenCalled();
}

it('should be called redirectToAuth function', () => {
  const loginService = TestBed.inject(LoginService);
  spyOn(loginService, 'redirectToAuth').and.callFake; 
  component. handleLogin();
  expect(loginSerive.redirectToAuth).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy!. I like how devs are still reaching onto this issue!.
I have moved to a different team and no longer work with the UI team, thanks for the answer tho!.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a service involved and you are supposed to **"UNIT"** test the Component, you're supposed to mock the service and expect that its method was called when you call the `handleLogin` method on your Component.

Something like this:

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { LoginService } from '../../services/login.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';

describe('Component: Login', () => {

  let component: LoginComponent;
  let service: LoginService;
  let spy: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new LoginService();
    component = new LoginComponent(service);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    service = null;
    component = null;
  });

  describe('Method: handleLogin', () => {

    it('should call the `redirectToAuth` method on the `LoginService`', () => {
      spy = spyOn(service, 'redirectToAuth');
      component.handleLogin();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });

});
```